# How to add more bots in Counter Strike?

Tags: counter-strike

I have set both `mp_autoteambalance` and `mp_limitteams` to 0, but the maximum number of bots I can play against is 10, and I would like to play against 20 bots, instaed. I mean, me against all bots.

Is there any other command to carry out that?

Comment: Are you going through the "start server" mode? When did you execute these commands?

Comment: Although the docs say otherwise, 0 tends to mean default as opposed to "no limit" in Valve games, which could mean you are still limiting the number of bots to 10. Try mp_limitteams 20. Also, make sure you add bots to the other team specifically, bot_add_t for terrorist and bot_add_ct for counter-terrorist.

Comment: i want to add bots but i don't know how

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing

> mp_teams_unbalance_limit 20

Answer (score 1):

Check if max players is set to 20 or above. You can find it under the create server options. Moreover you can set Maxplayers from console by typing

> Maxplayers 25

After Setting Maxplayers to a new value. Remember to restart the server to reflect the changes.